# Silverlight Automation with Powershell

Tags: silverlight, powershell, automation

I want to know if I can automate a Silverlight application with Powershell. If so, is there sample code or a website that has more information about it. So far, I haven't find any useful resources in developing a script to automate Silverlight. I know a similar question was asked here on this site, but the link in the answer no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I've used C# and [Telerik's testing framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework) for automating Silverlight and WPF. It's free and once configured - easy to use. Since Powershell stays on top of the .Net, I guess you can reuse framework's API or libs. I personally don't see why favor Powershell over C# here.

Comment: I didn't know Telerik had a free tool. I've used their Test Studio, but it hasn't worked for a while now. Is this better than Test Studio?

Comment: Actualy as far as I know the Studio uses the Framework.